# Clone a div that contains "customized" jQueryUI datePicker

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, datepicker, clone

I have a div that contains 3 fields

You can see the image here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jj7Z.jpg

I'm cloning this div with this plugin
http://sroucheray.org/blog/demos/jquery-dynamic-form/

My problems are:

- It doesn't clone correctly datePicker.
- I'm using validate form plugin, but I guess this plugin is not prepared to validate cloned elements

Is there any easy code, other plugin or some functions I should use for doing this sequence?

- Verify user has filled the 3 fields of the actual div
- If so, clone the div and create a new set of 3 fields. Also, clone datePicker correctly
- If user clicks the delete button, erase last div (last 3 fields)
- When form submitted, post all fields correctly

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to a problem just like that with the date picker and cloning it.  My solution was to remove the date picker prior to the cloning the elements.  Then after cloning the elements, initialize the datepicker on the clone.

Comment: This line of code was the solution. jQuery(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker'); After cloning, I run that line of code, and then I assign the datePickers again...