# Tempus Dominus Datepicker widget not cloning properly in Django Model Formset when using Dynamic Formset Library

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I have a model formset set up using [Django Dynamic Formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) along with [Crispy Forms](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms) and the [Tempus Dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) datepicker library. It's a simple formset for users to add operating expense line entries -- date, category, description, and amount.

My datepicker works correctly with a non-dynamic formset. However, when using dynamic formsets and a new form is added, the widget ends up targeting the last form in the formset that it was cloned from and not the current form (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymtNZ.jpg). Instead of incrementing properly (i.e. form_3, form_4, form_5, etc.), it just refers to the last form of the formset (i.e. form_2) before the new ones are added. As a result, if I try to toggle the datepickers in any of the dynamically added forms, it just triggers the one in form_2. Regular text fields clone correctly without any problems.

As you can see in lines 19-23 of opex.html, I'm attempting to implement the destroy and re-initialize functions as suggested by some older Stack Overflow posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719063/when-adding-a-new-inline-to-my-formset-my-datepickers-stop-working), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940483/using-a-form-with-custom-field-widgets-in-a-modelformset-factory), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633798/clone-a-div-that-contains-customized-jqueryui-datepicker)) but I'm a JS noob so I'm not sure how to proceed.

**models.py**

```python
class OpEx(models.Model):
    GEN_EXP = 'GE'
    OFFICE_SUP = 'OS'
    NR_EXP = 'NR'
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        (GEN_EXP, 'General Expenses'),
        (OFFICE_SUP, 'Office Supplies'),
        (NR_EXP, 'Non-Recurring Expenses'),
    ]
    exp_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    exp_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=GEN_EXP)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    amount = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Amount ($)', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**forms.py**

```python
class OpExEntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OpEx
        exclude = ('id', 'exp_user')

class OpExFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OpExFormSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'POST'
        self.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.form_show_labels = False
        self.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('exp_date', css_class='col-sm-2'),
                Column('category', css_class='col-sm-3'),
                Column('description', css_class='col-sm-4'),
                Column(PrependedText('amount', "<span class='fa fa-dollar-sign'"), css_class='col-sm-2'),
                css_class='opex-formset-row'
            )
        )
        self.render_required_fields = True
        self.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Update operating expenses'))
```

**views.py**

```python
def opex(request):
    OpExFormSet = modelformset_factory(OpEx, exclude=('id', 'exp_user'),
                                       widgets={'exp_date': DatePicker(attrs={'append': 'fa fa-calendar'})},
                                       form=OpExEntryForm, extra=0, can_delete=True)
    helper = OpExFormSetHelper()
    queryset = OpEx.objects.filter(exp_user=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OpExFormSet(request.POST, queryset=queryset)
        # Irrelevant code...
    else:
        formset = OpExFormSet(queryset=queryset)

    return render(request, 'opex.html', {'formset': formset, 'helper': helper})
```

**opex.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block extra_head %}
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% crispy formset helper %}

<!-- Load Django Dynamic Formset -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.opex-formset-row').formset({
        addText : 'add another',
        deleteText : 'remove',
        added: function (row) {
                    var datePicker = $(row).find('input[name$="exp_date"]');
                    if (datePicker.length > 0) {
                        datePicker.datetimepicker('destroy');
                    }
        }
    });
})
</script>

{% endblock %}
```